# Wrong encoding in Websphere.MQ communication

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq, mq

I recently encountered the problem with wrong encoding of the message data that I'm trying to send from one MQManager to another.

My C# code that sends the message go as follows:

```
var mqMessage = new MQMessage()
{
    CharacterSet = MQC.MQCCSI_Q_MGR,
    Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING
};

mqMessage.MessageId = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(message.MessageId);
mqMessage.WriteString(message.Message);
writeQueue.Put(mqMessage, _putMsgOptions);
```

Despite the fact that both MQManagers (source and destination) has the the same code page (852) in configuration set, message "WARSZAWA" on the destination MQManager is decoded as "WAęS]AWA".

Where am I making the problem?

Comment: MQMessage class does not have MessageIdEncoding property. Tried to compile your snippet but it does not compile. I guess you have missed an equals after MessageId, the line should have been mqMessage.MessageId = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(message.MessageId);

Comment: Yeah sure, I've edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this knowledgecenter article:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q111220_.htm

The WriteString method doesn't convert character data when you set CharacterSet = MQC.MQCCSI_Q_MGR, so you are sending your data in Unicode.

Depending on how you read it on the receiving side, this might cause your problem.

I suggest that you set CharacterSet of the messages to the CCSID you want to use. Every message denotes the codepage used for the character data in it, you shouldn't ever depend on the CCSID of the queue manager.

Comment: I tried to set the CharacterSet to specific number, but there was still the problem I've described.

Comment: At first I didn't understand your answer, but in the end it was correct ;). The problem was encoding the message using the MQC.MQCCSI_Q_MGR as you've mentiond and trying to decode the message using different character set. When I set the fixed codepage on the message the problem was solved ;). Thanks